# Syntax Error using Vacuum Into on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, vacuum

I'm trying to make a backup of a database in an Android application, and I was pointed to the VACUUM INTO query. However, when I try to call it, I get a syntax error around "INTO":

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTO": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: VACUUM INTO 'Test'
```

The String itself:

```
String query = "VACUUM INTO 'Test'";
```

I've tried using double quotes, single quotes, different path names, .db, no file type, including and excluding the database name - always the same error.

Is INTO not supported on Android's implementation of SQLite?

Comment: `VACUUM INTO` was added in 3.27, which is new enough it's unlikely to be present on any Android version.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's what I feared. Thank you.

Comment: Plus Android doesn't support the backup api that's been around forever. They don't make it easy.